# How to prove ((x :: xs) = (y :: ys)) given (x = y) & (xs = ys)

Tags: idris

I am learning Idris and I have a bit of a noob question.

I am doing exercise 2 of chapter 8.3 of the book on type driven development with Idris. The point is to implement `DecEq` for your own `Vector`. This is how far I got:

```
data Vect : Nat -> Type -> Type where
  Nil : Vect 0 elem
  (::) : elem -> Vect n elem -> Vect (S n) elem

headUnequal : {xs : Vect n a} -> {ys : Vect n a} -> (contra : (x = y) -> Void) -> ((x :: xs) = (y :: ys)) -> Void
headUnequal contra Refl = contra Refl

tailsUnequal : {xs : Vect n a} -> {ys : Vect n a} -> (contra : (xs = ys) -> Void) -> ((x :: xs) = (y :: ys)) -> Void
tailsUnequal contra Refl = contra Refl

headAndTailEq : {xs : Vect n a} -> {ys : Vect n a} -> (xEqY : x = y) -> (xsEqYs : xs = ys) -> ((x :: xs) = (y :: ys))
headAndTailEq xEqY xsEqYs = ?hole

implementation DecEq a => DecEq (Vect n a) where
  decEq [] [] = Yes Refl
  decEq (x :: xs) (y :: ys) =
    case decEq x y of
      No xNeqY => No $ headUnequal xNeqY
      Yes xEqY => case decEq xs ys of
        No xsNeqYs => No $ tailsUnequal xsNeqYs
        Yes xsEqYs => Yes $ headAndTailEq xEqY xsEqYs
```

How do I fill `?hole`?

I've seen the solution on `https://github.com/edwinb/TypeDD-Samples/blob/master/Chapter8/Exercises/ex_8_3.idr`. With that knowledge I can make my solution work:

```
implementation DecEq a => DecEq (Vect n a) where
  decEq [] [] = Yes Refl
  decEq (x :: xs) (y :: ys) =
    case decEq x y of
      No xNeqY => No $ headUnequal xNeqY
      Yes Refl => case decEq xs ys of
        No xsNeqYs => No $ tailsUnequal xsNeqYs
        Yes Refl => Yes Refl
```

But honestly, why does this work? Why does the final `Yes Refl` only work if I don't name the proofs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important difference is the value matching in the `case`-blocks, not the naming of the proofs. If you inspect the first `case` with

```
  decEq (x :: xs) (y :: ys) =
    case decEq x y of
      No xNeqY => No $ headUnequal xNeqY
      Yes Refl => ?hole
```

you will see, that the `?hole` only needs `Dec (x :: xs = x :: ys)`. In your version on the other hand, `?hole` is `Dec (x :: xs = y :: ys)`:

```
  decEq (x :: xs) (y :: ys) =
    case decEq x y of
      No xNeqY => No $ headUnequal xNeqY
      Yes xEqY => ?hole
```

Here, `xEqY : x = y`. Idris has no special understanding of `=`, so this simply means, that there is a value `xEqY` that has the type `x = y` (and there is no further inspection on what `xEqY` could be). If you match on `Refl`, Idris can unify `x` and `y`, because `Refl` is a constructor for `x = x` - the values are the same. Thus you gain more information with pattern matching; instead of an opaque variable name, you get a concrete value. As a rule of thumb: always pattern match until you have enough information on the right hand side.

With this, your proof can also be implemented easily:

```
headAndTailEq : {xs : Vect n a} -> {ys : Vect n a} -> (xEqY : x = y) -> (xsEqYs : xs = ys) -> ((x :: xs) = (y :: ys))
headAndTailEq Refl Refl = Refl
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I assumed that since `=` only has one constructor the effect would be the same.

Comment: Having just one constructor does not guarantee that you can actually construct a value. 3 = 5 is a valid type, but you cannot construct a value for this using Refl.

Comment: But in `Yes xEqY` there is already a value, so it must be `Yes Refl`. So I guess this could be inferred, though I haven't thought about all the consequences.